# Is the method of a telekinetic throwing people a probable combat technique?

Tags: magic, warfare, fight

My world is set in the time of the Inca's. Every 100 births, a telekinetic is born, someone who can move objects and people with their mind. The common way for a telekinetic to fight other tribes and other telekinetic is to send them flying into other stuff.

The question: is this technique

1. viable by users of telekinesis
2. simple, easy to learn, and requires no weapons
3. uses the environment
4. is not very creative, i.e. can easily be thought of quickly
5. can be applied in most environments

How the PK works: The average is an exertion of force equal to 9000 N, with the lower end being around 6000 N and the upper end being around 13000 N. The telekinetic is unrefined in the movement, being able to move relatively large objects (like a person) but not small objects. They also cannot move things in complex trajectories.

### The main goal of the question

The main goal of the question is to ascertain whether a world can be used as a weapon, by sending the target flying into everything.

Comment: Sure, why not. Acceleration of a 90Kg person for a couple of seconds by 9KNewtons would be equivalent to greater than terminal velocity from a fall - and onto a hard surface, pretty devastating. I'm not clear what the problem for us to solve is. Could you take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for our guidelines. See also the [ask] section, and see if you can edit something into your querry for us to get our teeth into.

Comment: Ok, I will do that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AngryMuppet I finished editing it

Comment: if it is on a battle field why wouldn't the kinetic just need to unbalance an opponent? Then those fighting alongside can take advantage of the unbalanced opponent while using more conventional weapons.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor because I was looking for a way for the kinetic to do it themselves, without assistance, so the telekinetic people could fight as individuals.

Comment: Fromwhat I've read being picked up and thrown by an elephant was not very healthy.  If the telekinetics can throw people with at least asmuch force as an elephant can, they should be at least as dangerous throwing peopla as elephants can be.

Comment: This reminds me so much of "Defend Your Castle". Good times...

Comment: What is the last sentence in the post actually meant to say?  Currently it's "The main goal of the question is to ascertain whether a world can be used as a weapon, by sending the target flying into everything."  Yes, if a world is thrown at someone then it will do damage unless it's a much, much, much smaller world after all than the one at Disney.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I meant if you take the whole universe and throw it at a target. Practically, though, you would just send the person flying at the speed of light through the universe

Comment: That does not match up with the rest of the question - 13000 N is not going to send anything flying at the speed of light unless it is sustained on a tiny object for a very long time.  (Even then, the most it can do is approach light speed, c is a hard limit.)

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I meant it non literally. Just really hard and fast is what I meant. : )

Comment: Given that you are asking about made up rules in your world, it seems that the only person that can really answer most of this is you....

Comment: Eventually those telekinetics would learn to push spears instead of men, hello NLOS ballistae. If lack of control is a problem, make spears a size of a man.

Answer (score 6):

With a force of nearly a tonne equivalent, your "average" telekinetic can produce an acceleration of around 10 G on a person.  Simply maintaining this for a couple seconds *in an upward direction*, then turning their attention to the next target, will instantly remove the victim from the fight, and give them enough upward momentum to induce a fatal impact when they fall back to Earth.  If they're in a tight formation or combat melee, it's likely this fall will also injure or kill another combatant (though in melee, there's no way to be sure which side the second victim is on, so this is best employed at a distance).

Comment: How much finesse does it take to literally toss someone straight up in the air?  If you're ten or fifteen degrees off vertical, they still die, just not where they were when you tossed them -- and if their control is much worse than that, the tribe should be drowning them as soon as their power is discovered, for its own protection.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question. The only problem is water environments, if there is a large body of water then will it break the fall?

Comment: @Braiyden If the fight happens on the beach, then just push your foe into the water and run away. When they come at you again you are no longer at the beach. So push them into something else.

Comment: @user99559 people still die when falling into water in normal world, when say dropped off an airplane without a parachute. So your tossed enemy will also die.

Comment: @user99559 Two seconds upward at 10 G gives a maximum height high enough to hit terminal velocity on the way back down -- a fall into water at that speed will kill you just as dead as if you landed on concrete.

Answer (score 2):

**It Seems Fine**

It is believable that *force push* is the most basic thing you can do with telekinesis. It is short range, imprecise, and pushes as hard as they possibly can.

It also sounds safe (for you) and deadly (for the other guy) if you can do it from ten metres away. It doesn't matter what weapons or skills the other person has -- they are going flying.

The only drawback is how much effort the push takes. If you can only push  as hard as you can it might be tiring. So people would train to only push as hard as necessary, or make a more focused blast. Of course it is up to you whether weaker and smaller blasts use less effort.

Comment: Can this be done without any knowledge? Like if the telekinetic doesn't receive combat training, never practices, and doesn't try to develop their powers, can they still do this effectively in combat?

Comment: @Braiyden Telekinetic or not, someone with no combat experience who finds themself in the middle of a battle, is likely terrified and not effective at ANYTHING.

Comment: @Braiyden  If your hero has a way to avoid the terror, then it is up to you how easy it is to use their powers. Maybe it takes decades of training to do anything. Maybe every telekinetic is an intuitive killing machine. Just try to keep it consistent to not confuse the readers.

Answer (score 1):

**Obviously yes**

Hitting a man into a stone is as good as hitting a stone into a man, if that stone is heavy enough. So, whoever that telekinetic is tossing with his superpower will definitely suffer. You don't even need to be creative about where to push your target, up and away would do.

**But... There are better uses for this power!**

If hitting a man into a stone is as good as hitting a stone into a man, why not throwing a stone at your enemies instead of throwing them one by one? Hello cannonball, hello stone bowling, hello siege artillery, hello shrapnel (toss a half-orb filled with small stones, applying force to the half-orb), hello many other things like a ballista (toss a spear a size of man, feathered if you want stability). Just train your side of telekinesis users to ramp up precision and assault your enemies from VERY afar, hello frikking METEOR SHOWER. Why picking cherries when you can pick a whole cake?